# React.cloneElement passing props issue

Tags: reactjs

I'm using React.cloneElement cause I want to dynamically open a component on a modal. But since I want to control the style when it appears in a modal I decided to use the cloneElement. I attached a CodeSand demo that will describe my code generally. My issue is that I cannot access the props that I'm passing to the cloned element (which call 'test' on the [CodeSand example](https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-bhaskara-rb7p1?file=/lowerSon.js)).

Any ideas why?
What I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you are wrapping the components with `div` and when you map the `Children` it will add the prop on `div` element and not in `Hello` component.

here is the updated code:

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Hello from "./Hello";
import Parent from "./Parent";

class App extends React.Component {
  renderSomthing() {
    return [<Hello />, <Hello />];
  }
  render() {
    return <Parent>{this.renderSomthing()}</Parent>;
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Working Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-maxwell-cwt53?file=/index.js:0-343

Comment: so if the Div has to be there, is there still a way to access the prop?

Comment: No you need to map across the actual children only in order to pass the props